# Error Executing Makefiles on Netbeans 7.1

Tags: java, netbeans, makefile

Am trying to execute a makefile which will automatically runs a compiled front end of a java code i have written. the contents of the make file is as follows:

```
       build: compile test

compile:
javac lexer/*.java
javac symbols/*.java
javac inter/*.java
javac parser/*.java
javac main/*.java

test:
@for i in `(cd tests; ls *.t | sed -e 's/.t$$//')`;\
    do echo $$i.t;\
    java main.Main <tests/$$i.t >tmp/$$i.i;\
    diff tests/$$i.i tmp/$$i.i;\
done

 clean:
(cd lexer; rm *.class)
(cd symbols; rm *.class)
(cd inter; rm *.class)
(cd parser; rm *.class)
(cd main; rm *.class)

 yacc:
/usr/ccs/bin/yacc -v doc/front.y
rm y.tab.c
mv y.output doc
```

When i run make from netbeans, i get this error on the terminal:

```
         javac lexer/*.java
           Makefile:4: recipe for target `compile' failed
           /bin/sh: javac: command not found
            make: *** [compile] Error 127


             MAKE FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 660ms)
```

Please how do i solve this problem.?

Answer (score 0):

The error means the Java compiler (javac) cannot be found.

Your JAVA_HOME variable needs to be set and also appended to PATH.

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin 
export Path:=$(JAVA_HOME);$(Path)
```

Add these lines to the start of your makefile.

Comment: Thanks James...I added this after the build:compile test on my makefile:  export JAVA_HOME=<C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06>
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin but error till persists, where am i getting it wrong?

Comment: @Igbe Chukwudi Edited my answer. I wrongly assumed you were using Unix, not Windows.

Comment: @ JamesB, it still gives me this error:                            Makefile:2: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.                                                               here is a view of my makefile:                                                                                                                               set JAVA_HOME=%<C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06>%
set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
build: compile test

compile:
 javac lexer/*.java
 javac symbols/*.java
 javac inter/*.java
 javac parser/*.java
 javac main/*.java
     ...................................

Comment: i still get the original javac command not found. do you think this is a problem from Netbeans?